# Issue with upgrading project to Visual Studio 2019

Tags: asp.net, visual-studio-2017, upgrade, visual-studio-2019

I upgraded existing web forms app (c#) from Visual Studio 2017 Enterprise to 2019. While code is working fine, when I open default.aspx page - I get 123 errors (while code compiles fine). If I open it back in 2017 version - no errors

I had addressed couple of the errors but not sure what to do with the rest. Especially puzzling that code compiles with 0 errors. Errors show only if I open default.aspx

Most errors are CS0103 - the name 'name here' doesn't exist in the current context
Few errors CS0400 - the type or namespace 'project name' could not be found in the global namespace
Few CS1061 - 'default_aspx' doesn't contain definition for 'Context'...

I don't understand how it still compiles without errors and works? What changed with upgrade that those errors popped up? All those names and namespaces exist and there were no changes other than upgrade. New requirements? How to fix it?

Comment: Hi Alla, any update for this issue? Does that issue still block you :)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Found a solution:

This is happening to projects that are using v1.0.0 of Microsoft.Net.Compilers. To work around this problem you need to update to the latest stable version which is 3.0.0.

All errors disappeared.

Comment: Hi Alla, glad to know you've found the solution to resolve this issue! Please consider marking it as answer to share the useful info to others with similar issue, and we can archive this issue :)  See [can I ...](https://stackoverflow.com/help/self-answer)

Comment: Hi Alla, glad to know you've found the solution to resolve this issue! Please consider accepting it as answer to change its status to `Answered`. See [can I answer my own question..](https://stackoverflow.com/help/self-answer), Just a reminder :)

Answer (score 0):

Looks like something broken with `VS Intellisense` since the compile and build sueeccded.

1.Before you open the web form project in VS2019, navigate to its Solution Directory and delete the hidden `.vs` folder there, after that open the project in VS2019 to check if it helps.

2.If the issue persists, try cleaning the VS component cache after close all VS instance:

Go C:\Users\xxx\AppData\Local\Microsoft\VisualStudio directory, you can find many `15.xx` and `16.xx` folders there, feel free to delete all `ComponentModelCache` folders in them and restart VS.

Comment: Thank you, Lance. I did first suggestion - no luck, same 130+ errors. I don't have the folder you specified, probably because we are using Onedrive and local drive is being redirected(?)...

Comment: Do you get the error when building it in VS in local machine? If so, go solution folder in WIndows File system, you can find the .vs folder.(View=>Hidden Items to see it), delete it can help in many scenarios... And my suggestion 1 and 2 is two steps to clean the cache, you need to do both them. Also, try a rebuild to check if it helps :) Let me know if it still no luck :(

Comment: Did all that.. Visual Studio is installed on my local machine, however the project is on the shared drive. Deleted Local/Temp folder too.. Still the same. Rebuild it - 0 compiled errors, 99+ errors in aspx page