# Thousands of compilation warnings and errors after upgrading Visual Studio 2019

Tags: c#, winforms, visual-studio-2019

I have a solution with various project types (MVC Net 5.0.11, NetStandard2.0, .Net Framework 4.8). The main app is a WinForms project.

I just upgraded VS to 16.11.5 (from 16.11.4) and NET5.0.11 (from NET5.0.10).

Now when I compile the main project, I'm getting over 5500 warnings such as:

> Warning   CS0436  The type 'SomeClass' in 'C:\App\SomeClass.cs' conflicts with the imported type 'SomeClass' in 'MainApp, Version=5.0.54.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=null'. Using the type defined in 'C:\App\SomeClass.cs'.

And over 1500 errors such as:

> Error CS0121  The call is ambiguous between the following methods or properties: 'MyNamespace.GetFieldNames(System.Collections.Generic.IEnumerable)' and 'MyNamespace.GetFieldNames(System.Collections.Generic.IEnumerable)'

If I manually delete the main project's `bin` and `obj` folders, load the solution, and compile (or run), the project compiles (or runs) without errors... as expected.

Further compiles or runs will result in the above errors. Also, the WinForms Designer throws a multitude of different exceptions on any of the forms I try to view.

VS activity log has the following warnings:

> Request for "Microsoft.VisualStudio.Shell.Internal.SettingsManager (1.0)" from Process denied because the service is only exposed RemoteExclusiveClient, LiveShareGuest.

> Request for proxy to "Microsoft.VisualStudio.Shell.Internal.SettingsManager (1.0)" is declined: ServiceAudienceMismatch.

And the following error:

> Microsoft.ServiceHub.Framework.ServiceActivationFailedException: Activating the "Microsoft.VisualStudio.FileSystem.LocalFileSystemProvider (1.0)" service failed. ---> System.InvalidCastException: Unable to cast object of type 'Microsoft.VisualStudio.PlatformUI.Packages.FileSystem.LocalFileSystemProvider' to type 'Microsoft.VisualStudio.RpcContracts.FileSystem.IRemoteFileSystemProvider'.at Microsoft.VisualStudio.Utilities.ServiceBroker.GlobalBrokeredServiceContainer.ProfferedServiceFactory.d__28`1.MoveNext() --- End of stack trace from previous location where exception was thrown ---at System.Runtime.CompilerServices.TaskAwaiter.ThrowForNonSuccess(Task task)at System.Runtime.CompilerServices.TaskAwaiter.HandleNonSuccessAndDebuggerNotification(Task task)at System.Threading.Tasks.ValueTask`1.get_Result()at System.Runtime.CompilerServices.ValueTaskAwaiter`1.GetResult()at Microsoft.VisualStudio.Utilities.ServiceBroker.GlobalBrokeredServiceContainer.View.<GetProxyAsync>d__19`1.MoveNext() --- End of inner exception stack trace ---

Any ideas on why this is happening, and preferably solutions?

Comment: Libraries were updated.  Delete bin and obj folders is not a bad idea. You should always do a full build when the libraries were updated.

Comment: Have you already read this question[Issue with upgrading project to Visual Studio 2019](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/58506615/issue-with-upgrading-project-to-visual-studio-2019)? Just an idea.

Comment: VS was already 2019 (v16.11.4). I upgrade it everytime a new update comes out. The same with NET5.

Comment: I manually deleted the bin and obj folders of all projects, rebuild the solution and it works  only once. The same errors occur on successive compiles.

Comment: what happened to me sometimes in the past, is that the references point to files from the build instead of projects from the solution. Meaning that rebuilding doesn't actually copy them properly. Well, I really don't know what the cause was, but removing the reference(s) and re-adding them seemed to work

Comment: You'll get these kind of errors when a project references itself.  Works okayish on a clean build since the output file does not yet exist, but guaranteed ambiguous definition when you build again.  Hard to guess how that happened, use the detailed build log to look at the /reference arguments passed to the compiler.

Comment: @HansPassant How can I can generate a detailed build log?

Comment: Ok I generated a detailed build log. I don't see a circular reference for the main app. The build is succeeding, but opening forms in the designer results in various errors. one of them here: https://stackoverflow.com/q/69565895/524861