# Error when opening a form in the designer

Tags: c#, winforms, visual-studio-2019

I upgraded VS2019 from 16.11.4 to 16.11.5 and when I open forms in the designer I'm getting this error:

[image]

This is a followup problem related to my other problem here: [Thousands of compilation warnings and errors after upgrading Visual Studio 2019](https://stackoverflow.com/q/69559574/524861)

VS activity log has the following warnings:

> Request for "Microsoft.VisualStudio.Shell.Internal.SettingsManager (1.0)" from Process denied because the service is only exposed RemoteExclusiveClient, LiveShareGuest.

> Request for proxy to "Microsoft.VisualStudio.Shell.Internal.SettingsManager (1.0)" is declined: ServiceAudienceMismatch.

And the following error:

> Microsoft.ServiceHub.Framework.ServiceActivationFailedException: Activating the "Microsoft.VisualStudio.FileSystem.LocalFileSystemProvider (1.0)" service failed. ---> System.InvalidCastException: Unable to cast object of type 'Microsoft.VisualStudio.PlatformUI.Packages.FileSystem.LocalFileSystemProvider' to type 'Microsoft.VisualStudio.RpcContracts.FileSystem.IRemoteFileSystemProvider'.at Microsoft.VisualStudio.Utilities.ServiceBroker.GlobalBrokeredServiceContainer.ProfferedServiceFactory.d__28`1.MoveNext() --- End of stack trace from previous location where exception was thrown ---at System.Runtime.CompilerServices.TaskAwaiter.ThrowForNonSuccess(Task task)at System.Runtime.CompilerServices.TaskAwaiter.HandleNonSuccessAndDebuggerNotification(Task task)at System.Threading.Tasks.ValueTask`1.get_Result()at System.Runtime.CompilerServices.ValueTaskAwaiter`1.GetResult()at Microsoft.VisualStudio.Utilities.ServiceBroker.GlobalBrokeredServiceContainer.View.<GetProxyAsync>d__19`1.MoveNext() --- End of inner exception stack trace ---

Comment: Is this happening with all forms or just one?

Comment: All forms. This is also related to my other problem: https://stackoverflow.com/q/69559574/524861

Comment: Can you create a new empty form, save and close, and then open that in the Designer?

Comment: Any empry form works. All other forms no.

Comment: All I can suggest, is a fairly laborious trial and error process. Take one of your forms that does not open; comment out all bar the constructor in the code behind; comment out all the object references in Designer.cs. It should now open as an empty form. Then gradually uncomment objects in the Designer.cs to try to isolate which object/s is/are causing the issue. That hopefully will point you in the right direction.